# Angular 2 HTTP Service (Youtube API)

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube-api

I am new to this, so please excuse if I am not getting something obvious here.

Here is the project on Github, if you want to give it a try: https://git.io/vXtWp

Anyhow, I have a simple Angular 2 service that calls YouTube Api, it looks like this:

[image]

Then I have an app.component.ts that looks like this:
[image]

And HTML file:

[image]

My application doesn't work though, it shows as loading with following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormControl: (?, ?, ?). metadata_resolver.js:499
```

This is what it looks like in the browser:
[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I've spent 2 hours, having no luck figuring this issue out...

Comment: Please add code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Do you have `FormControl` somewhere as constructor parameter?. Why do you list it in `providers: []`?

Comment: I've added a Github repo to description, if someone wants to give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input [FormControl]="search">
```

should be

```
<input [formControl]="search">
        ^
```

This needs to be the selector or input name of a directive or component, not the class name.

`FormControl` should be removed from `imports: [...]` in `@NgModule()`. Only modules should be listed in `imports` of `@NgModule()` not individual classes.

There is no need to list `ReactiveFormsModule` in `providers`. Adding it to `import` is enough.

Comment: I've done what you said and it still doesn't work for some reason... here is the project on Github, can you please take a look? https://git.io/vXtWp

Comment: Why do you have `FormControl` added to `providers:`? Can you please try adding `FormsModule` in addition to `ReactiveFormsModule` to `imports`?

Comment: Removed FormControl from providers imports. I added FormsModule to imports... it's still doesn't do anything, errors ...

Comment: The exact same error as you explained in your question or a different error? The code in your repo seemed fine to me besides what I already mentioned.

Comment: Couple of other errors, which were fixed by doing: import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'; and import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; ... then it all started to work... Thanks for all your help, much appreciated.